# A about dense graph

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

let assume no distinction is made between a function and its graph. let $A,B\subset{\\R}$ and $A\subset B$ . Assume  $f:B  \rightarrow  {\\R}$ and $g:{\\R} \rightarrow {\\R}$ are functions. Let $g$ be a dense subsets of $f$. Is true that $g$ has nonempty intersection with $f\restriction_A.$ If not how if $A$ is open. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: *Let* $g$ *be a function  dense subsets of* $f$. --- You should review this sentence, as it doesn't make sense. Perhaps during your writing/editing some words were accidentally left out.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro it fixed

Comment: How can $g$ be a subset of $f$ when the domain of $f$ is possibly a proper subset of $R$?